# How to show private posts to non logged in users on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, private, posts

The reason I'm not making the posts public is because I want the posts to stay hidden in my posts list widget as they filter out automatically private posts. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to coding so i would appreciate what specific file to edit and where to add this code specifically, thanks.

Comment: The request doesn't really make a whole lot of sense: "Private" posts are specifically posts that you need to be logged in and qualified to view. To hide the posts from your post list widget, the more direct way to go will be to filter the widget output or query. Very possibly, there is already a bujilt-in way to accomplish that, but the most practical one for you will depend on widget you're using. So, can you identify it?

Comment: You're absolutely right that I could simply filter them out through the use of tags or taxonomy but that would require a lot more work in terms of editing the posts later down the line rather than just changing them from private to public. So private posts absolutely require you to be logged in to view, theres no workaround for this through the use of modifying the functions file?

Comment: i found this code from a whitespider article that allows you to change the user role to make private posts viewable to certain groups but I was wondering if this could be modified to allow for non logged in users? code below

Comment: 1
 /*
2
 * Make Private Posts visible to Subscribers
3
 * Typically only visible to admin or editor
4
 */
5
 <?php
6
 function whitespider_private_posts_subscribers(){
7
  $subRole = get_role( 'subscriber' );
8
  $subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
9
 $subRole->add_cap( 'read_private_pages' );
10
 }
11
 add_action( 'init', 'ws_private_posts_subscribers' );
12
 ?>